# onclick of my submit button, the array stored in localstorage does not add the new item but is replaced while using react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to add data from a single input field to an array which i want to store in localstorage but when i submit input button, the item is stored at first but if i try to store a second item, the array previous item is replaced with the newly typed item data instead of adding to it like i'd expect an array to behave. i don't understand this behaviour. i will really really appreciate a detailed explanation since i'm using react to do this.
This is my code below

**input field**

```
    import React from "react";
import "./addoption.css";

function AddOption({ validateOption }) {
  const handleAddoption = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputValue = e.target.elements[0].value.trim();
    validateOption(inputValue);
    e.target.elements[0].value = "";
  };

  return (
    <div className="addoption">
      <form onSubmit={handleAddoption}>
        <input type="text" name="list" />
        <button>Add Option</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddOption;
```

*this is my code to add the input data to the localstorage *

```
  const handleAddoption = (option) => {
    if (!option) {
      return setErrorhandler("Enter valid value to add item");
    } else if (listItems.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
      return setErrorhandler("This option already exists!");
    }
    const array = localStorage.getItem("Options");
    let items = [];
    if (array) {
      items = JSON.parse(array);
    }
    let storedArray = JSON.stringify(items.push(option));

    localStorage.setItem("options", storedArray);

    setListItems({ options: items });
  };
``
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push` certainly mutates the array, but it's return value isn't the array, it's the new length of the array. You may want to do the mutation separate from the JSON serializing.

The reason for the overwriting is because you're using two different storage keys for getting and setting. You are not getting what was stored so you are only appending new data to an empty array. Make sure you also use the same key to both retrieve ***and*** set the localStorage.

```
const handleAddoption = (option) => {
  if (!option) {
    return setErrorhandler("Enter valid value to add item");
  } else if (listItems.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
    return setErrorhandler("This option already exists!");
  }
  const array = localStorage.getItem("options");
  let items = [];
  if (array) {
    items = JSON.parse(array);
  }

  items.push(option);

  localStorage.setItem("options", JSON.stringify(items));

  setListItems({ options: items });
};
```

A more optimal solution would be to read in and initialize the `options` state ***from*** localStorage, and use an `useEffect` hook to just persist state updates ***back*** to localStorage. This way is a little easier to manage.

Example:

```
const initializeState = () => ({
  // ... other listItems initial state
  options: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("options")) || [],
});

const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(initializeState());

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("options", JSON.stringify(listItems.options));
}, [listItems.options]);

const handleAddoption = (option) => {
  if (!option) {
    return setErrorhandler("Enter valid value to add item");
  } else if (listItems.options.indexOf(option) > -1) {
    return setErrorhandler("This option already exists!");
  }
  
  setListItems(prevState => ({
    ...prevState
    options: prevState.options.concat(option),
  }));
};
```

Comment: i do understand what you're saying but can you send me a code snippet that i can use

Comment: @EnomaVictor Is the one provided in answer not usable? Or are you referring to my "more optimal" suggestion?

Comment: I really do appreciate your answer but i'm still new to react and would prefer a code snippet that i can use directly  in my project to compare my work with yours

Comment: @EnomaVictor Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding you, but the first code snippet in my answer is just a modification of your provided code, corrected for storage keys and array mutation. It *should* be directly useable, is it not? I don't mind clarifying any part of my answer that may be unclear to you as I'd prefer you understand the issue and a solution.

Comment: I've done with your help. Thanks man . thanks so so much. I do really appreciate. God bless

Comment: @EnomaVictor Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck.